# scala json parse and get a nested key and value

Tags: scala, jackson, json4s

I have a json like below,

I have json like below I need to extract the value from them

```
{
    "filed1": "value1",
    "message": {
        "payload": [{
            "type": ["Extra","ID"],
             info": {
                "value": 8
            }
        }, {
            "type": ["Free"],
            info": {
                "value": 99
            }
        }, {
            "type": ["Actual"],
             info": {
                "value": 100
            }
        }]
    },
    "code": "0000"
}


{
    "filed1": "value1",
    "message": {
        "payload": [{
            "type": ["Extra", "new"],
            "value": 9
        }]
    },
    "code": "0001"
}
```

from the above  two types of json .

If the input json has list of **type** keys then look for type field which has element **Extra** and get the value inside info

If the input json has one **type** key  then check type field , if it has element **Extra** and get the direct va;ue

I am trying like below for type but it fails for list of types json, i.e first json input

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
import org.json4s.JsonDSL._

val json = parse(myjsonString, true)
val field = compact(render(json \\ "type"))

val ok = field.contains("[\"Extra\"")

if(ok == true){
println("value " +  compact(render(json \\ "value")))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `json4s` to do the work for you. Specifically, you need to use the `extract` method on the `json` to convert it into your particular data structure. Once you have done that you can process it as Scala types.

This is my attempt at matching the structure of your JSON with Scala case classes:

```
case class PayloadInfo(value: Int)
case class Payload(`type`: List[String], info: PayloadInfo)
case class Message(payload: List[Payload])
case class Full(filed1: String, message: Message, code: String)

implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

val json = parse(myjsonString, true)

val full = json.extract[Full]

val res = full.message.payload.filter(_.`type`.contains("Extra"))
```

[ The backticks around `type` are required because it is a reserved word ]

I may have got the types a bit wrong but this should give you the idea of how to go about it.

You can also process the `JValue`s directly but that is going to be much messier.